# Banner not working correctly

Tags: jquery, banner

My banner rotates fine if I click on the right arrow but when I click on the left arrow then I get some problems. In my firebug the active turns into inactive and it stays that way.

My js

```
    $(".nav_arrows").click(function(){
    $direction = ($(this).hasClass("left-arrow") ? "left" : "right");
    var activeBanner = 100;
    if($direction == "right"){
        $(".inactive-banner-copy").css("left","100%").show();
        activeBanner = -100;
        if($(".active-banner-copy").next().length < 1){
            $(".banner-copy-wrapper").eq(0).animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
                $(this).addClass("active-banner-copy").removeClass("inactive-banner-copy");
            });
        }else{
            $(".active-banner-copy").next().animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
                $(this).addClass("active-banner-copy").removeClass("inactive-banner-copy");
            });
        }
    }else{ //left
        $(".inactive-banner-copy").css("left","-100%").show().fadeTo(250, 0);
        if($(".active-banner-copy").prev().length < 1){
            $(".banner-copy-wrapper").eq($(".banner-copy-wrapper").length-1).animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
                $(this).addClass("active-banner-copy").removeClass("inactive-banner-copy");
            });
        }else{
            $(".active-banner-copy").prev().animate({"left":0+"%","opacity":1}, 500,function(){
                $(this).addClass("inactive-banner-copy").removeClass("active-banner-copy");
            });
        }
    }

    $(".active-banner-copy").animate({"left":activeBanner+"%","opacity":0}, 500,function(){
        $(this).addClass("inactive-banner-copy").removeClass("active-banner-copy");
    });

});
```

My jsfiddle:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x7Lhgmb1/1/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? it's really hard to solve it like this. And what kind of problems you are getting? and error in the console?

Comment: I added the jsfiddle to my question. The problem is that if you click the left arrow so that it goes brown fairy, blue fairy and then brown fairy and if you click on the right arrow it doesn't go to the blue fairy. You have to click the right arrow twice for it to go to the blue fairy. There is no error in the console.

Comment: It's working in jsfiddle. Have you tried with different browsers?

Comment: In jsfiddle, if you inspect the image and click the arrow then you can see what I mean in the html section of firebug.

Comment: It looks like it's working but it isn't.

Comment: do you want src value of the img tag to be changed?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to swop `$(this).addClass("inactive-banner-copy").removeClass("active-banner-copy");` around so that it became `$(this).addClass("active-banner-copy").removeClass("inactive-banner-copy");`